# In contractual law, what's the difference between clause and article?

Tags: legalese

As the heading suggests, I'm wondering what the difference is between a clause and an article in a contract or agreement.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a legal question.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Indeed it is! Or, perhaps rather: a legalese question :) Are you saying I've posted in the wrong forum? If so, what forum would you suggest I post in? Thank you!

Comment: You can look it up in Black's Law Dictionary online. A clause is a paragraph on a topic. An article **can be** the numbers used to number a level in a contract. This is not really a "legal question".

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Going to depend on the country, and possibly even sub-parts of the country (province, state, etc.). So no general answer is possible. You need to ask a lawyer licensed in the specic location you want to know about.

Comment: @Dan That is not true. Generally, countries all have similar contracts. In the US, there may be state differences but the major part of a contract will be the same. The same is true in Canada for the English speaking parts. This is all common law and the lingo is the same.

Comment: If you are looking up terminology in a legal dictionary, that makes this a legal question. That was my point -- that those who know the law are better suited to answer this ? and so this should be on a different forum.

Comment: I really can't speak about whether all English-speaking countries define legal terms the same way or not; I think that is FAR beyond the scope of this forum, which is about learning English generally, not about learning law.

Comment: In particular, don't be confused: *article* and *clause* also have completely unrelated meanings when talking about grammar (and in other contexts too).

Comment: This is arguably outside the scope of ELL SE, can be looked up in a dictionary, and lacks research, so I'm closing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no firm rules on how a legal document may be divided, and [in practice it varies between different legal traditions.](https://weagree.com/weblog/articles-sections-or-clauses/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20firm%20rules,dividers%20and%20subdivided%20in%20Sections.)

In England, a contract may often be constructed as a series of clauses. Each clause is a single agreement made between the parties.

In the US, legal documents may be divided into articles, and each article into sections, and perhaps subsections.

As an example, [the US constitution is divided into seven articles.](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/article-1/)  Each article is divided into sections. The first article has 10 sections. Each section has one or more clauses.

So in brief, a clause is a paragraph in a legal document.  An article is a section of a legal document, that may include one or usually more clauses.

Comment: This is wrong. Law in the US is based on common law and this stuff is exactly the same. All contracts are a series of clauses.

Comment: https://weagree.com/weblog/articles-sections-or-clauses/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20firm%20rules,dividers%20and%20subdivided%20in%20Sections.

Comment: The legal tradition in the US is quite different from England or Scotland.

Comment: Thank you, James K – excellent answer as always!